# WildCARD search using lucene in a large file containing 100 millions Strings taking too much time. i want the result in 1-2 seconds

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, large-files

**i have a file size 1.43 gb. the file contains 100 millions strings ( 3 - 80 characters length) separated line by line in the file. i am doing WILDCARD search on the file using lucene. right now i am creating one document for each string. i want total count of the search keyword (*searchkeyword*).here is my code**

**lucene.demo.java**

public class LuceneDemo {

```
//a path to directory where Lucene will store index files
private static String indexDirectory = "C:\\indextofile";
// a path to directory which contains data files that need to be indexed
private static String dataDirectory = "C:\\indexofilef";
public static int count = 0;

private Searcher indexSearcher;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {  
    LuceneDemo luceneDemo = new LuceneDemo();   
    //create Lucene index
    luceneDemo.createLuceneIndex();
    //create IndexSearcher
    luceneDemo.createIndexSearcher();
    luceneDemo.termQueryExample();


}

private void createLuceneIndex(){
    Indexer indexer = new Indexer(indexDirectory,dataDirectory);
    //Create IndexWriter
    indexer.createIndexWriter();
    try {
        //Index data
        indexer.indexData();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}




private void createIndexSearcher() throws CorruptIndexException, IOException{
    /* Create instance of IndexSearcher 
     */
    indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexDirectory);      
}

private void termQueryExample() throws CorruptIndexException, IOException{
    try
    {
    Directory directory = FSDirectory.getDirectory(indexDirectory);
    //IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
    BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(102400000); 
    Term term = new Term("reversecontent", "bubble*com");
    Query query = new WildcardQuery(term);
    Hits hits = indexSearcher.search(query);    

    System.out.println("######## Hits :"+hits.length());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Indexer.java**

public class Indexer {
    private IndexWriter indexWriter;

```
/*Location of directory where index files are stored */
private String indexDirectory ;

/*Location of data directory */
private String dataDirectory ;
public String  FIELD_CONTENTS = "contents";
public Indexer(String indexDirectory, String dataDirectory){
    this.indexDirectory = indexDirectory ;
    this.dataDirectory = dataDirectory ;
}


void createIndexWriter(){
    if(indexWriter == null){
        try{
            //Create instance of Directory where index files will be stored
            Directory fsDirectory =  FSDirectory.getDirectory(indexDirectory);
            /* Create instance of analyzer, which will be used to tokenize
            the input data */
            Analyzer standardAnalyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
            //Create a new index
            boolean create = true;
            //Create the instance of deletion policy
            IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy = 
                                    new KeepOnlyLastCommitDeletionPolicy(); 
            indexWriter =
                 new IndexWriter(fsDirectory,standardAnalyzer,create,
                         deletionPolicy,IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
        }catch(IOException ie){
            System.out.println("Error in creating IndexWriter");
            throw new RuntimeException(ie);
        }
    }
}


void indexData() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    File[] files = getFilesToBeIndxed();
    for(File file:files){

         FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);  
            // To store the contents read via File Reader  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);                                                   
            // Read br and store a line in 'data', print data  
            String data;  
           System.out.println("start");
            while((data = br.readLine()) != null)   
            {  
                String newdata = data+".com";
                Document doc = new Document();
                //doc.add(new Field("content", newdata,
                //      Store.NO, Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
                doc.add(new Field("reversecontent", new StringBuffer(newdata).reverse().toString(),
                    Store.NO, Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
                indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
            } 
         System.out.println("end");
        // Add these fields to a Lucene Document

        //Step 3: Add this document to Lucene Index.
    }
    /* Requests an "optimize" operation on an index, priming the
    index for the fastest available search */
    indexWriter.optimize();
    System.out.println("optimization done");
    /*
     * Commits all changes to the index and closes all associated files. 
     */
    indexWriter.close();
}

private File[] getFilesToBeIndxed(){
    File dataDir  = new File(dataDirectory);
    if(!dataDir.exists()){
        throw new RuntimeException(dataDirectory+" does not exist");
    }
    File[] files = dataDir.listFiles();
    return files;
}
```

}

Comment: did you consider using something like hadoop?

Comment: If you have enough memory, I would suggest loading the entire dataset into memory using a NavigableMap to index the wildcard search.  This would take a few GBs, but the lookup would be sub micro-second.  If don't have this much memory you can implement the same structure using a memory mapped file.  This way the speed would depend on how much you can keep in memory. Either way using more memory or an SSD would be a good idea.

Comment: @DevZer0  no i didn't.. have you done something like this in hadoop.??

Comment: which version are you using? if not the latest, try that.

Comment: @phani   i am using the latest one..lucene 4.3

Comment: This doesn't look correct. Since 4.0 IndexWriter constructor requires an Analyzer and an IndexWriterConfig as constructor parameters.

Comment: Why are you searching on reversed content?  That's a typical strategy for supporting leading wildcards, yes, but I would think it would only hurt in this case, as the (unreversed) suffix, I would certainly assume, is the more common element of the search.

Comment: And, to second @jpountz comment, IndexSearcher hasn't had a ctor taking a String arg since 2.9